# I want the logo and heading in center for all screen size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**HTML CODE:**

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <header class="header-area row">
            <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="logo-area row">
                <div class="col-xs-7 col-xs-offset-5 col-sm-7 col-sm-offset-5">
                    <a href="index.html"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/logo.png" alt="V" /></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="heading row">
                <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-7 col-md-offset-5">
                    <h1>I love design </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>
```

**CSS CODE:**

```
.header-area .logo-area img {
    width: 90px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 52px 0 120px;
}
.img-responsive {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[image: Sample]

I tried in many ways but i failed.The solution should be done using bootstrap.Please help me.

Comment: The column you have the image in isn't centered...that seems an odd choice. If you just put the image in the row (without the column) it seem to center fine using the usual techniques - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/PqLNEV

Comment: Yes it was odd choice.Thanks for suggestion....

Answer (score 1):

here is a solution, just add css `display:inline-block`  and put all your tag between this html thg `<center > </center>`

here is modified code

---

```css
.inline{
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
}
.header-area .logo-area img {
    width: 90px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 52px 0 120px;
}
.img-responsive {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
 <center>
 <div class="container-fluid">
        <header class="header-area row">
            <div class="container-fluid inline">
            <div class="logo-area row">
                <div class="col-xs-7 col-xs-offset-5 col-sm-7 col-sm-offset-5">
                    <a href="index.html"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/logo.png" alt="V" /></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container-fluid inline">
            <div class="heading row">
                <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-7 col-md-offset-5">
                    <h1>I love design </h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>
    </center>`
```

good luck..

Comment: The `<center>` tag has been deprecated...other centering methods should be used.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center

Answer (score 0):

try adding 1 more class `text-center` to `conrainer-fluid` and remove any margins you applied in your css

```
<div class="container-fluid text-center">
    <header class="header-area row">
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="logo-area row">
            <div class="col-xs-7 col-xs-offset-5 col-sm-7 col-sm-offset-5">
                <a href="index.html"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/logo.png" alt="V" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid text-center">
        <div class="heading row">
            <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-7 col-md-offset-5">
                <h1>I love design </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </header>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this style in you `CSS` file:

```
.center-block {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

And also add apply this class on your image:

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="images/logo.png" class=".center-block" alt="V" />
```

***[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/94007)***